brightness adjustment on honor magicbook 16 with Fedora 40 operating system
The brightness on the laptop begins to behave randomly (increases to 100% or decreases), this often happens if you use the touchpad. I'm new, I tried to solve the issue with AI, but it didn't help. The field of this F1 F2 also stops working 12th Gen Intel® Core™ i5-12450H × 12 Intel® Graphics (ADL GT2) Linux 6.11.3-200.fc40.x86_64 version GNOME 46
